# Find max of the list more generally

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm trying to find max of the list more generally. I applied wildcard.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){ }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? extends T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> c){
        T max= c.iterator().next();
        for(T element : c){
            if(element.compareTo(max)>0) max=element;//Compile error
        }
        return max; 
    }
}
```

Compiler gave me error message:

```
incompatible types: T cannot be converted to CAP#1
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Compareble<? extends T> declared in method <T>max(Collection<? extends T>)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends T from capture ? extends T
```

I have a some doubts about this error message

**What does mean fresh type-variable?** In the JLS 4.1 written that *There are two kinds of type in the Java programming language: primitive types and reference types* and *There is also a special null type, the type of the expression* `null`, *which has no name.*

**What is the CAP#1 fresh type-variable?**

Comment: A compiler error is not a crash.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){ }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> c){
        T max= c.iterator().next();
        for(T element : c){
            if(element.compareTo(max)>0) max=element;
        }
        return max; 
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The problem is that T needs to be comparable to T, or any superclass of T.

You had T as comparable to a class that was either T, or some subclass of T, which was not sufficient.

Or, looking at it another way, the `? extends T` in the Comparator might not be the same class as the `? extends T` in the Collection.

This was the cause of those errors.

FYI, I'm not sure you benefit from the wildcard in `Collection<? extends T>`. `Collection<T>` will work fine.

Comment: It doesnt work to. I'm confused. Can you answer my questions?

Comment: @Dmitrii +1 You have types `T` and `? extends T` in the Collection.  Unfortunately you have another `? extends T` in Comparable and the first and second `?` are not considered the same.  By using `? super T` it can be `T` or any of its parents which is not ambiguous and the super classes of T are know (but not all its possible sub types)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey in the string `T max= c.iterator().next()` we dont know about type returned be `next()`. Does compiler considering this type as lower bound (`T` in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Ordering` from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Ordering.from(comparator).max(collection);
```